# How to cast "io.vertx.mutiny.sqlclient.Rowset" to List of Map without knowing the columns?

Tags: java, vert.x, quarkus

I am new to Quarkus and I am fetching the records from the table, but query written by 3rd party user, so it may happen we don't know the database fully, in that how can we convert Rowset to "List of Map" or to any "Pojo class" or "JsonArray "?

```
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;
import io.vertx.mutiny.pgclient.PgPool;
import io.vertx.mutiny.sqlclient.RowSet;
import io.vertx.mutiny.sqlclient.Tuple;
import io.vertx.sqlclient.Row;
public Uni<TableRQ> getTableRQ(int ids) {
    try {
        sql = "select * from "+vdnm+"ai_request_parameter where id in ($1)";

        return client.preparedQuery(sql).execute(Tuple.of(ids))
            .onItem().transform(pgRowSet -> {
                JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
                for (Row row : pgRowSet) {
                    // Here if I know columns than I know how to do it, but I don't know so How can we achieve it?
                }
                return jsonArray;
            });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can get the column name via `Row#getColumnName(int)` https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/sqlclient/Row.html#getColumnName-int-

Comment: Is there is anyway to directly convert Rowset to Bean/POJO class?

Comment: @user3458271 with Vert.x 4 there is Row/POJO mapping. Otherwise in Quarkus you can try Hibernate Reactive.

Comment: No, have to do it without hibernate and using Quarkus only

Answer (score 0):

You might need to transform some data before converting to a JsonObject / POJO, so I'm providing a few different solutions with more or less control.

Solution 1: RowSet<Row> to JsonArray (Small control)

```
JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
for (Row row : pgRowSet) {
    JsonObject jsonObject = row.toJson();
    jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
}
return jsonArray;
```

Solution 2: RowSet<Row> to JsonArray (Full control)

```
JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
for (Row row : pgRowSet) {

    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    for (int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
        String columnName = row.getColumnName(i);
        Object columnValue = row.getValue(i);
        jsonObject.put(columnName, columnValue);
    }

    jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
}
return jsonArray;
```

Assuming you want to convert a Row to a POJO class (in this case MyElement is the POJO class).

Solution 3: RowSet<Row> to List<MyElement> (Small control)

```
List<MyElement> elementsList = new ArrayList<MyElement>();
for (Row row : pgRowSet) {
    JsonObject jsonObject = row.toJson();
    MyElement element = jsonObject.mapTo(MyElement.class);
    elementsList.add(element);
}
return elementsList;
```

Solution 4: RowSet<Row> to List<MyElement> (Full control)

```
List<MyElement> elementsList = new ArrayList<MyElement>();
for (Row row : pgRowSet) {

    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    for (int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
        String columnName = row.getColumnName(i);
        Object columnValue = row.getValue(i);
        jsonObject.put(columnName, columnValue);
    }

    MyElement element = jsonObject.mapTo(MyElement.class);
    elementsList.add(element);
}
return elementsList;
```